# Check if record doesn't belong to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my index, I want to display all of the Game records.  I want to split them up into ones that are already associated with the current user, and ones that are not.

```
def index
  @games = current_user.games
  @others = Game.where(game not in @games)  # how do i do this?
end
```

I'm wondering if this type of query exists, or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: whoa that is pretty sweet.  this is a new project, so i think i might

Comment: So lemme give this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@others = Game.where('id not in (:games)', games: @games)
```

Or:

```
@others = Game.where('id not in (?)', @games)
```

Notice the use of parenthesis when you use `not in` or `in` operators.

Comment: do you mean to say `:games`?

Comment: no such column: game: SELECT "games".* FROM "games"  WHERE (game not in (22,23,24))

Comment: Sorry assumed that was column.  Try with id instead, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you were mean to use Rails 4, you could do it just using new API called `where.not`. Like this:

`Game.where.not(game: SOMETHING)`

Use fresh Rails :)